# Backbone - How to prevent models from being added to and removed from collections on server side validation failures

Tags: backbone.js

For example, if I do a destroy on a model and the server returns a 4xx/5xx, the error callback handler is called but the model is removed from the collection anyway. How I do prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Backbone is optimistic about this starting in v0.9. From the docs at http://backbonejs.org/#upgrading

> Creating and destroying models is now optimistic. Pass {wait: true} if you need the previous behavior of waiting for the server to acknowledge success. You can now also pass {wait: true} to save calls.

So all you have to do is set the `{wait: true}` flag in your save:

`myModel.save(null, {wait: true});`

or in your delete:

`myModel.destroy({wait: true})`

Comment: Thanks! I read that in the docs but I thought it'd just wait for a response from the server and then add/destroy. I realize now that would make little sense. I must have been tired! :)